# Cannot Get ACTION_VIEW Data From Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

In my manifest file I have the following:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

At the top of my main activity in onCreate, I have:

```
mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
```

In my onResume in main activity, I have:

```
if(mIntent != null){
        if(mIntent.getExtras() != null){
            Log.d("INTENTDATA", "" +mIntent.getExtras());
        }

    }
```

Even though mIntent isn't null, mIntent.getExtras() returns null. When I tried mIntent.getData(), it also returned null.

Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Use getIntent at onCreate instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

I needed to call getIntent();

```
mIntent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(mIntent.getAction())) {
        Log.d("INTENTDATA", "ACTION_VIEW");
        if(mIntent.getData() != null){
            Log.d("INTENTDATA", "" +mIntent.getData());
        }

    }
```